# How to control the display font in the 'Find Usages' window in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, fonts

The title says it: I left click and choose 'Find Usages' for a function name, and comes up the 'Find Usages' window. Can I change the font size for text in that window. Running Netbeans 7.01 on Debian Squeeze.

**Update:**

These suggestions from Netbeans faq and misc. forums I have tried:

- Start with fontsize paramaeter:

  netbeans --fontsize 14
- Modify netbeans.conf in the install folder and add fontsize option:

  netbeans_default_options ="--fontsize 14 -J-Xms32m ...."

None of these have any effect.